# Find where font is stored

Tags: css, fonts

I'm setting up a site on a subdomain for a client, it needs to look the same. They are using `Futura-pro` font, but I cannot find where it is, so I can use it on the subdomain site. The subdomain site calls all the same css and js files, and the font is referenced, but just doesn't render.
Is there a way to find out where it is? Or that possible that it will only work on certain domains?

Comment: can you provide the sitename so we can look at the CSS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are using [TypeKit](https://typekit.com/), and yes, most of the fonts are sold to work on a single domain however i think it's okay to use it on subdomain of the domain you have license for.

you can use your chrome network tool to see where are assets loading from.

Comment: So currently the subdomain is not setup, and is just a ip address. Once it's setup it should work in theory?

Comment: if it's subdomain of the same domain then yes. it should.

Comment: http://blog.typekit.com/2010/08/09/wildcard-domains/ you might need to allow it in your typekit account.